# Flask Socket-IO Having a server wait for a client callback

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am building a pure python application with flask socket-io. Currently, I am trying to have the server emit an event to a specific client and wait for the callback before moving on.
This is my Server.py

```
import socketio
import eventlet

sio = socketio.Server(async_handlers=False)
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio)

@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    nm = None
    def namee(name):
        print(name) # this has the value and is trying to assign it to nm
        nonlocal nm
        nm = name
    sio.emit('name_', "name plz", callback=namee)
    print(nm) # this shouldn't be None, but it is
    print(sid, "in lobby")

@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect', sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 5000)), app)
```

And this is my client.py

```
import sys
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()


@sio.event
def connect():
    print("you have connected to the server")


@sio.event
def connect_error(data):
    print("The connection failed!")


@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print("You have left the server")

@sio.event
def name_(data):
    print("name asked for")
    return "test"

def main():
    sio.connect('http://localhost:5000')
    print('Your sid is', sio.sid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried using time.sleep() but that delayed the whole process. I also tried making a while loop

```
while nm is None:
    pass
```

but that kicked the client off the server and a while later, the server crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `call()` method instead of `emit()`.

```
    nm = sio.call('name_', "name plz")
    print(nm)
```

I recommend that you move this logic outside of the `connect` handler though. This handler is just to accept or reject the connection, it is not supposed to block for a long period of time. Do this in a regular handler that you use after the connection has been established.